# How can I play songs via putty?

Tags: server, sound, windows, putty

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 Server and I installed putty on Windows. Is it possible to listen to the audio from the server in putty? If it is possible, please share the appropriate steps.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/422628/is-it-possible-to-stream-an-audio-signal-over-an-ssh-connection

Comment: Google search found this, https://scarygliders.net/2012/04/06/get-audio-with-your-xrdpx11rdp-connections-lan-or-remote/

Comment: Could you please clarify what your use case is exactly? There are various options to realise what you seem to want with just as various advantages and disadvantages. Do you want to play back audio files on the client that reside on the server? Do you want to listen to an audio broadcast distributed by the server? Do you want to hear system sounds during a remote-desktop session?

Comment: I want to listen the audio  which is playing in server using putty...